# org-capture with reference to file in which it was invoked

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Is there a way to configure org-capture so that, if I create a note from within a certain file, it will include a link to that file?

Answer (score 2):

If I do `M-x describe-variable <RET> org-capture-templates`, I learn that `%f` expands to the filename you desire and `%F` the full path of the file.

From there, you should be able to cook a link.